# Function call ambiguity (user-defined conversion and Derived2Base pointer conversion)

Tags: c++, c++11

What is the reason for ambiguity in the function call in the code below?

I get that there are two viable functions here, as the compiler tells in the `ERROR` message (shown below at the end)

1) `candidate: operator==(Base*, Base*)`

-> requires user defined conversion from `SmartPtr` to `Base*` for the first parameter

-> requires `Derived*` to `Base*` implicit (**?**) conversion

2)`candidate: bool operator==(const SmartPtr&, const Base*)`

-> requires addition of top level const (exact match) for first parameter

-> requires `Derived*` to `Base*` implicit (**?**) conversion

From above it is quite clear that `operator==` defined inside `SmartPtr` is the better match (considering the first parameter and second one being same)

**CODE**:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<class T> class SmartPtr
{
    public:

    operator T*() { return pointee__;}

    inline friend bool operator==(const SmartPtr& lhs, const T* rhs){
        return lhs.pointee__ == rhs;
    }

    private:

    T* pointee__;
};

struct Base{};

class Derived:public Base{};

int main()
{
    SmartPtr<Base> sp;
    Derived * dp;

    cout<<"Hello World"<< (sp==dp);

    return 0;
}
```

**ERROR**:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:38:30: error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘SmartPtr’ and ‘Derived*’)
     cout<<"Hello World"<< (sp==dp);
                            ~~^~~~
main.cpp:38:30: note: candidate: operator==(Base*, Base*) 
main.cpp:19:24: note: candidate: bool operator==(const SmartPtr&, const Base*)
     inline friend bool operator==(const SmartPtr& lhs, const T* rhs){
                        ^~~~~~~~
```

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest reading [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Best_viable_function).

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but names that contain two consecutive underscores (`pointer__`) and names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From above it is quite clear that operator== defined inside SmartPtr is the better match (considering the first parameter)

Not exactly: the first is converted to `SmartPtr &` to `SmartPtr const &`

And the second requires **two** conversions:

1) from `Derived *` to `Base *`

2) and from `Base *` to `Base const *`

If you define

```
Derived * dp;
```

a pointer to `const`

```
Derived const * dp;
```

The ambiguity disappear and the code compile.

The same if you define `sp` `const`

```
SmartPtr<Base> const sp{};
```

Disappear also if you modify the `operator==()` inside `SmartPtr` to accept a `Base *` (not a `Base const *`) as second parameter.

Comment: How did I miss the ```const``` conversion?! That's why sometimes it's good to have someone else take a  look at your code. Thanks a lot! Also I am guessing you meant ```const Derived * dp``` and not ```Derived const * dp```

Comment: another solution was to template the function as ```template<class U> inline friend bool operator==(const SmartPtr& lhs, const U* rhs){
        return lhs.pointee__ == rhs;
    }```

Comment: @User10482 - The rule is: `const` is applied to the element on the left; if there isn't an element on the left, it's applied to the element on the right. So `const Derived *` and `Derived const *` are the same thing: modifiable pointers to constant `Derived` objects. Different is `Derived * const`: a constant pointer to a modifiable `Derived` object.